# Boolean algebra

Tags: boolean, logic, algebra

Can anyone help me with a little Boolean algebra. Wolfram alpha doesn't seem to like this very much. The problem is huge so I'm only showing a small small part of it.

`( ( A' or B or C )' or ( A or D )' or D')'`

thank you.

This is the whole problem.
[image: picture of the problem]

the blue is what i have posted

Comment: And your problem and question are?

Comment: Use a tool like [Logic Friday](http://sontrak.com) for this. Also your diagram does not match the expression as written.

Answer (score 1):

The DNF form of your written equation is (A'D)+(BD)+(CD)

More forms on [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=not+%28+not+%28+not+A+or+B+or+C+%29+or+not+%28+A+or+D+%29+or+not+D%29)

Answer (score 0):

If the `'` in your sample code stands for negativity, then in C# or Java you'd have:

```
boolean A,B,C,D;
```

and then:

```
if(!(!A || B || C) || !(A || D) || !D)
{
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: Looking back, it looks like the part that I circled does not match the boolean statement provided. I gave `( ( A' or B or C )' or ( A or D )' or D')'` when infact it should be `( ( A' or B or C )' or ( A or B )' or D')'`. If it had been `( ( A' or B or C )' or ( A or D )' or D')'` the minimization would have been `( ( A' or B or C ) and D')` as the `(a || d ) && d` reduces to just `d`